# Is it worthwhile to hire a tax consultant in the Netherlands

Tags: taxes, netherlands

My tax situation is not overly complicated, and I wonder if I should hire a professional or do it myself.
Basically I have employment income, plus stocks which I earn from the company, and that’s the whole story.

In my first year in the Netherlands, I hired a professional, and got some 1400 euro in return. This year I tried to fill in my taxes myself, and in the government website they calculate I would not get any returns.

Basically I am wondering if a professional would be able to do some magic which would earn me a similar amount again, or if what the website is calculating is precise.

Comment: Your taxes might be more complicated if some of your income comes from outside the Netherlands, or if you owe taxes in some other countries. That complexity might make you want to hire a consultant.

Comment: The money you got during the first year might be related to the move and the way withholding works in the Netherlands, especially if you didn't work the whole year. I am not up-to-date on the rules and I don't know your situation but it could explain the discrepancy and your accountant would not necessarily be able to secure the same result this year.

Comment: Compare the two tax submissions to see why the first resulted in a refund and the second did not. Alternatively, as the first year might have been an anomaly, and assuming your situation is now stable and will remain the same in future years, using a tax consultant for your second year submission might be worthwhile to give you a ‘base’ return that you can rely on when doing future returns yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself, if your situation is simple, it is better to do it yourself.
I did the tax declaration by myself, then I paid someone to do it, and the outcome was exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

There is an intermediate solution between "do it yourself" and hiring a professional.  You can look for software.  Automated software should be able to cover the most common cases at a fraction of the cost of a professional, but helping you to remember to claim your rights.  In particular as a foreigner, you might not be aware of all the ways in which the Dutch tax office likes to give tax breaks to people who earn well.